# Can't import pandas in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, conda

I'm running python3.6 in a conda enviroment, pandas is installed. I run my code in terminal and it works, but when I run it in pycharm it shows:

```
>  import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I checked my interpreter, checked the packages installed, AND PANDAS IS THERE!, but I don't know why it is not recognizing it.

[image: Packages installed]

Comment: edit configurations and check the interpretter specifically for the file you are trying to run

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't know how to do that

Comment: Just type `python` in the inbuilt command prompt of Pycharm within your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm has many configuration, which can be a bit confusing at first.

First of all there are the interpreters configured in your environment, like the one you set up in your question.

Secondly there are specific configurations for running your application, you can create many *run* configurations for you project in order to run different files/modules with different interpreters (for example run the project with python3 project specific venv, and your tests using pytest interpreter)  [as explained here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

I think you didn't set the run/debug configurations to use this specific interpreter, or accidentally created a project `venv` that doesn't contains pandas yet.

By the way, it is very recommended to create project specific venv [as explained here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: I literally installed pycharm 30 minutes ago, so I don´t know what are you talking about

Comment: I added more information to the answer in order to be clearer

Comment: yep, you were right, i accidentally created a venv, i started from zero making sure to not create a venv and now its working, thanks!

Comment: You could change the `run` configured interpreter on the fly, no need to reboot projects.
And also- you can install all needed packages within the venv you you would use it. Venv is highly recommended for projects that will be later deployed on production servers!